# SQLsrv- Permission on Rows in Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, permissions

I need set permission on rows in table in SQL server for specific user. Is that possible? 
Example 
Users- A, B, C 
Table Test: 
1. Value - 5, User - A
2. Value - 6, User - B
3. Value - 7, User - A
For User A -> Select Value from Test -> Result is: 5, 7
For User B -> Select Value from Test -> Result is: 6
For User C -> Select Value from Test -> Result is: nothing

Comment: You can grant access to a columns

Comment: Would be good if your example was actually correct?

Comment: I´m sorry. It´s repaired

Answer (score 0):

This is easily achieved using Row Level Security provided by SQL Server 2016 and higher, or Azure SQL Database.

For this you need to create a `SECURITY POLICY`

For more details you can check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security)

**For earlier version of SQL server you can check this** [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966395.aspx)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I know what should I search :)

Comment: I have updated the link for previous versions of SQL also